# Windows 7 - Windows security center is turned off - safemode

Tags: windows-7

So via msconfig I enabled safemode with networking and rebooted to test some things.

When it started noticed after a while there was the little flag saying the security center was turned off. I was able to start it either when I tried to turn it on.

I couldn't find much info on this. Is it normal for the security center to be turned off during safe mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal for the security center to be turned off during safe mode?

Yes it is, since Safe Mode is running with the least amount of processes and drivers it can, to ensure the system starts up.

Safe Mode is intended only for system diagnostics, and having a bunch of security features enabled could/would just get in the way while trying to diagnose a system problem.

Comment: I did notice the services that the security center was dependent on were turned on, so is security center just disabled altogether for safe mode?

Comment: The two services it depends on (RPC and WMI) are fundamental to using and diagnosing Windows, hence they are left enabled in Safe Mode.  The Security Centre itself is _not_ required for Windows to run, nor to diagnose a failing system, so it's _not_ enabled in Safe Mode.

Comment: I have another question id like to ask but im wondering is to early to start another question or can I go and ask it?

Comment: Please do!  there's no imposed time limit between questions (that I'm aware of :) )  You may want to throw me an up-vote or an accepted answer (if, in fact, my answer was useful to you), as leaving multiple answered questions of yours unmarked will start to deter people form helping you. :)

Comment: I was definately going to give and upvote / best answer but it seems my reputation is too low. I will try my best to earn it (once I have I will go through my questions and make sure whoever helped gets their points.)